# How do you achieve the 'BST Property' in a Template Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

We recently started learning about binary search trees. We created one of our own using integers as our Key/Data. It's easy to achieve the BST property using an int key, but what happens when we template our tree? How do we achieve our BST property with say a char, string or foo? - These don't seem fitting for keys. Do we simply keep an int on our node and use that as our Key instead of our T data? Or, am I completely misunderstanding this concept all together?

---

In the following code example, the coder implements a template binary search tree, and he is using T as his key. He proceeds to run comparisons between T when inserting, etc. But what happens when T has no overload for comparison operators? This code falls apart correct?

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56188/binary-search-tree-implementation-using-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it fails to compile, which is a totally fine and correct outcome. His BST is a valid implementation for any valid key type, and fails to compile for incorrect key types. There's no reason to desire any other behaviour. It's the best possible outcome.

> These don't seem fitting for keys.

You're wrong. Any T with a comparison operator and a couple other bits like copy/move constructors is a fitting key.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. So if we want to pass in our own T into our tree, we must assure our T has the appropriate qualities so it can be handled by the tree?

Comment: @SebastianKing: If by appropriate qualities you mean "Any T with a comparison operator and copy/move constructors," then yes.

Comment: @SebastianKing Yep. You don't need to do this explicitly in C++ as the compiler will error.

Comment: yep that's what I meant. Alright thanks for the responses guys. Much appreciated. I'd upvote but I don't have the privileges.